# jQuery validate ignore jQuery-select2 inside a hidden div while validating a form

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, jquery-select2

How to ignore the `jquery-select2` element which is inside a hidden div when trying to validate a form?

```
<form id="form">
   <div id="hidden" style="display:none">
      <select id="select2">
         <option>1</option>
         <option>2</option>
      </select>
   </div>
</form>
```

I try bellow code but didn't works

```
<script>
   $("#form").validate({
   ignore: ":hidden",
      rules: {
        select2: {required: true,}
      }
   });

$("#select2").select2();
</script>
```

Comment: Your question makes no sense, as everything inside any hidden `div` will be ignored whether you declare `ignore: ":hidden"` or not, since the `":hidden"` setting is already the default.  Please explain.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery [.validate()](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/) method sort of initializes the form against the validation rules and/or their corresponding error messages.

To check if the form is valid or not, you will need to make a separate call.
Primarily, this is done by:

1. calling the [.valid()](https://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/) method.
2. chaining the `.form()` after`.validate()`, i.e. `$('#form').validate({rules:{}}).form();`
3. on form submit

Coming to question, here are some pointers:

1. Validation works with the name attribute:

> <select id="select2" **name="select2"**>

2. There is a typo (mismatch quotes) in the js code line no #1

> ```
> $("#form').validate({
>         ^
> ```

3. `ignore` may consists of any selector that can go into [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) method and has the default value as `:hidden`, so you can ignore (pun intended) this property/option

Below is a working snippet of the above:

- Click **Submit** to check if the form is valid or not
- Click **Toggle Select** to show/hide the select

```js
$("#form").validate({
  rules: {
   select2: {required: true},
   fname: {required: true}
  },
  messages: {
   select2: {required: " select is requirred"},
   fname: {required: " first name is required"}
  },
  invalidHandler: function(form) {
   $("#status").html("INVALID");
  },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $("#status").html("valid");
        }
    });
 $("#toggleSelect").click(function() {
  $("#hidden").toggle();
 });

$("#select2").select2();
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>


<form id="form">
 First Name: <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">
    
    <div id="hidden" style="display: none;">
  Select:  
   <select id="select2" name="select2">
   <option></option>
   <option>1</option>
   <option>2</option>
   </select>
    </div>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    
</form>
<br>
<input type="button" id="toggleSelect" value="Toggle Select">
<br>
<p id="status"></p>
```

Comment: you miss jQuery select2

Comment: I guess I did. But, it shouldn't be a problem as jQuery-validate will be independent of select2. If you initialize through `validate()` and provide rules   for elements with their name attribute, select2 or no select2 there shouldn't be any difference. Anyhow, I've updated the above snippet with select2. Hope, it clears your doubts.

Comment: jQuery Validate does not *"sort of"* initialize.... it absolutely initializes the plugin on your form.

Answer (score 0):

Your setting is also the default setting...

```
ignore: ":hidden"
```

It means that everything that's hidden will be ignored for validation.

> How to ignore the jquery-select2 element which is inside a hidden div when trying to validate a form?

Your question makes no sense, as everything inside any hidden `div` will be ignored whether you declare `ignore: ":hidden"` or not, since the `":hidden"` setting is already the default.

Since you also have this code...

```
rules: {
    select2: {required: true,}
```

it would seem that you do **not** really want to ignore the hidden select2 element.  If that's the case, construct a new jQuery Selector for `ignore` that selects all hidden elements *except* your select2 element.

Comment: This is a good point, but how can I select all visible select2 but ignore hidden select2? It looks like a single selector is not enought.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. In my case this was because I was running a `.valid()` on  'change' on all select2 elements.

```
$('.smart-select2').select2({
    ...
}.on('change', function() {
  $(this).valid()
}
```

So essentially this was running on all select elements (including hidden ones)...

Thus to fix I simply changed the above to:

```
$('.smart-select2').select2({
    ...
}.on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).is(':hidden')) return
  $(this).valid()
}
```